# Python: how to write a data struct to a file as text (not pickled)

Tags: python

Is there a way to write python data structs to a file as text.

e.g. an app is running and has a variable/object: OPTIONS = ('ON', 'OFF', )

I need to write/merge the OPTIONS tuple into another file, not as a 
pickled object, but as text, verbatim: OPTIONS = ('ON', 'OFF', )

I could traverse the tuple, and one by one write the elements into
the target file, but was wondering if there's an easier way.

note: if i do a "straight" write, i get the following:

```
fout.write(OPTIONS)
 ... 
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not tuple
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [repr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) (repr works well with things that have a `__repr__()` method):

```
>>> OPTIONS=('ON', 'OFF', )
>>> "OPTIONS="+repr(OPTIONS)
"OPTIONS=('ON', 'OFF')"
```

Comment: And ast.literal_eval can be useful to parse the text back to a Python data structure.

Answer (score 1):

`fout.write(str(OPTIONS))` does what you want in this case, but no doubt in many others it won't; `repr` instead of `str` may be closer to your desires (but then again it might not be, as you express them so vaguely and generally, beyond that single example).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your scope but you could use another serialisation/persistence system like [JSON](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), or [Twisted Jelly](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.spread.jelly.html) that are more human readable (there's others like [YAML](http://pyyaml.org/)).

I used jelly in some project for preferences files. It's really easy to use but you have to use repr() to save the data in human readable form and then eval() to read it back. So don't do that on everything because there's a security risk by using eval().

Here's a code example that prettify the representation (add indentation):

```
VERSION = 'v1.1'

def read_data(filename):
    return unjelly(eval(open(filename, 'r').read().replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')))

def write_data(filename, obj):
    dump = repr(jelly(obj))
    level = 0
    nice_dump = ['%s\n' % VERSION]
    for char in dump:
        if char == '[':
            if level > 0:
                nice_dump.append('\n' + '\t' * level)
            level += 1
        elif char == ']':
            level -= 1
        nice_dump.append(char)
    open(filename, 'w').write(''.join(nice_dump))
```